# d3.js : time scale and data : gape of some pixel between tick and data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis, timeline

I got a problem with the time axis so I search on the Web and I see that there is the same problem on the tutorial/exemple on the web :(

On this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lampalork/dm6ff3ua/ (it's just a fork of an exemple find on fiddle)

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient('bottom')
.ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
.tickSize(5)
.tickPadding(8);

    svg.selectAll('.chart')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date)); })
```

you can see the problem, if you look the time axis and the first bar chart you can see a gape of 3-4 pixel. I got the same problem on my work and I see this problem on other exemple of the web. Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
.attr('x', function(d) { return x(new Date(d.date)); })
```

is creating the date object with UTC timezone.  From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> Differences in assumed time zone
>
> Given a date string of "March 7, 2014", parse() assumes a local time
>   zone, but given an ISO format such as "2014-03-07" it will assume a
>   time zone of UTC. Therefore Date objects produced using those strings
>   will represent different moments in time unless the system is set with
>   a local time zone of UTC. This means that two date strings that appear
>   equivalent may result in two different values depending on the format
>   of the string that is being converted (this behavior is changed in
>   ECMAScript ed 6 so that both will be treated as local).

`d3` though is using local timezone to draw the ticks.

Instead do everything the d3 way and use [d3.time.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format).  In my timezone, here's the difference:

```
new Date("2012-03-20")
> Mon Mar 19 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse("2012-03-20")
> Tue Mar 20 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm6ff3ua/2/).

Comment: Brilliant, This is the real solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will have search a loooooonnnnnnnngggggggg time.